# Internel Server Error when installing Savanna

Tags: 12.04, openstack

I have installed OpenStack following the tutorial from [here](http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/).

It worked fine and I was able to login to dashboard.

But when I tried to install `Savanna` by following [this](http://savanna.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userdoc/installation.guide.html), I start getting this error when I login to dashboard.

Any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have installed not only Savanna service, but Savanna UI as well following this doc
http://savanna.readthedocs.org/en/latest/horizon/installation.guide.html

right?

Which version of OpenStack do you use?

I would recommend two things: first check that you correctly followed the instructions at each step. Second try to find Horizon logs on your system, they may have a clue.

And one more suggestion: for the further questions I would recommend using
https://ask.openstack.org/en/questions/

It is much more probable to find OpenStack users and experts there.