# Install python setup tools for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, python, openstack

I am trying to install **Savanna** in **OpenStack** but I am getting [this error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442108/internel-server-error-when-installing-savanna) that I have posted on askubuntu.com

Someone told me that it might happen because I have not right version of **python-setup-tools** installed for my Ubuntu.

I installed python using this command.

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-virtualenv python-dev
```

Can anyone tell me what is the right version and command to install python-setuptools?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option to try out Savanna is to use devstack in a virtual machine. I was using an Ubuntu 12.04 virtual instance in my tests. In that environment we need to execute the following commands to install devstack and Savanna API:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core
$ git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git
$ vi localrc  # edit localrc
ADMIN_PASSWORD=nova
MYSQL_PASSWORD=nova
RABBIT_PASSWORD=nova
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_TOKEN=nova

# Enable Swift
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,swift

SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2000f5
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1
SWIFT_DATA_DIR=$DEST/data

# Force checkout prerequsites
# FORCE_PREREQ=1

# keystone is now configured by default to use PKI as the token format which produces huge tokens.
# set UUID as keystone token format which is much shorter and easier to work with.
KEYSTONE_TOKEN_FORMAT=UUID

# Change the FLOATING_RANGE to whatever IPs VM is working in.
# In NAT mode it is subnet VMWare Fusion provides, in bridged mode it is your local network.
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.55.224/27

# Enable auto assignment of floating IPs. By default Savanna expects this setting to be enabled
EXTRA_OPTS=(auto_assign_floating_ip=True)

# Enable logging
SCREEN_LOGDIR=$DEST/logs/screen

$ ./stack.sh  # this will take a while to execute
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-virtualenv python-dev
$ virtualenv savanna-venv
$ savanna-venv/bin/pip install savanna
$ mkdir savanna-venv/etc
$ cp savanna-venv/share/savanna/savanna.conf.sample savanna-venv/etc/savanna.conf
# To start Savanna API:
$ savanna-venv/bin/python savanna-venv/bin/savanna-api --config-file savanna-venv/etc/savanna.conf
```

[Source](http://bighadoop.wordpress.com/2013/08/18/openstack-savanna-fast-hadoop-cluster-provisioning-on-openstack/).

Comment: I have tried this and got errors while installing through DevSTack